# Python tkinter: stick scroll bar to text widget to appear as if they are one widget

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I have a text widget, with an attached scroll bar. However, there always exists around 1px of space between them. I want it to appear as a single box with a built in scrollbar.

```
self.text_Widget = tk.Text(frame_Output)
    self.text_Widget.config(borderwidth='0', font='TkFixedFont', relief='flat', width='100')
    _text_ = '''Output will be present here during execution...'''
    self.text_Widget.insert('0.0', _text_)
    self.text_Widget.pack(anchor='w', expand='true', fill='both', ipadx='0', ipady='00', padx='0', pady='10', side='left')
    self.scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(frame_Output)
    self.scrollbar.config(orient='vertical')
    self.scrollbar.pack(anchor='w', expand='true', fill='y', ipadx='0', ipady='0', padx='0', pady='10', side='left')
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMwke.png)

Comment: I don't have the 1px space when running similar code.

Comment: Apparently, this is not at all possible. Looking at the native MacOs apps, they also clearly show the border.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to set the `highlightthickness` to zero.

---

By the way, `'0.0'` is not correct. Line numbers begin at 1, so the first character of a widget is `1.0`. Tkinter is a bit forgiving, but it's best to use the correct value.

Comment: even after setting highlightthickness to zero.. it still shows the same result. (I am on a mac os).         self.text_Output.config(borderwidth='0', font='TkFixedFont', highlightthickness='0', insertborderwidth='0')